# Why does a foreach loop which iterates more than 10,000 times run out of memory?

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I'm developing a PHP script that loops/iterates more that 10,000 times:

```
foreach ($array_with_items as $item) {

    // Instantiate the object
    $obj_car = new CarAds($puk, 'ENG', '5');

    $obj_car->detail1 = "Info about detail1";
    $obj_car->detail2 = "Info about detail2";
    $obj_car->detail3 = "Info about detail3";
    $obj_car->detail4 = "Info about detail4";

    // Saves to the database
    $obk_car->save;
}
```

When I run this code my machine runs out of memory. What can I do to clean the memory in this foreach cycle?

Comment: You write `$obj_car` and once `$obk_car`, is this intended?

Comment: You are creating an instance of CarAds at every iteration.

Comment: even if you fix the typeo `$obj_car->save;` is accessing a property, to call the save method you would use `$obj_car->save();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are instantiating as CarAds objects as your $array_with_items item count. Each one allocate memory.

After the save() method you should deallocate the object with the unset() function:

```
// Saves to the database
$obj_car->save;

// Unset unneeded object
unset($obj_car);
```

You can check your memory consumption with the memory_get_usage() (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Answer (score 5):

Try `unset($obk_car)` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

[`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the object at the end of the `foreach` loop

```
unset($obj_car);
```

If you still need more memory for your script, you can increase the [limit](http://php.net/memory-limit) in your `php.ini` at this line :

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

**Edit :**

- If you are on PHP >= 5.3.0 you can force garbage collectio by calling [`gc_collect_cycles`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)
- If you are using PHP >= 5.2, [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/) from IBM is an interesting read.

Comment: You can also remove any memory limit setting the parameters to -1

Comment: I'm sorry, I made some confusion with +1 and -1 and then +1 again. The Ajax script lost the last +1. I put it back. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: The edited question title explains that. The question was not "How to increase the limit" but "WHY it runs out". Increasing the limit without a reason will lead to just another error and server malfunction. One have to read whole question before andswer, not just some key words and then start writing automated answer.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel You are right, but I also gave him another solution. Thanks anyway, I'll take it into consideration next time. I edited the answer appropriately.

Comment: @spider No problem, you can remove the downvote now that the answer has been edited.

Comment: @Nacereddine I already removed it when I wrote my preceding comment :)

Comment: @Nacereddine. Interesting the gc_collect_cycles. I've used the unset to the object but I'm running out of memory in the same way. The code I'm using is more complex than the piece of code that I've write. I've more 4 foreach cycles outside the foreach that I show. The "gc_collect_cycles" will unset variables and objects? From the documentation I can't figure out what does this function...

Comment: @André it's not well documented on the page I linked, check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php) one instead and from that page : "It is also possible to force the collection of cycles even if the possible root buffer is not full yet. For this, you can use the gc_collect_cycles() function."

Comment: Alex, maybe the class allocate objects by itself so even if you unset() it you have memory leaks anyway. You can investigate of the class has a method to destroy the object. Did you wrote the class os is part of a well known framework? In this case which framework is?